# Display Currency and Percentage in one cell depending on what is entered

Tags: excel, formatting

I can format the cell to display Currency and Percentage, but can I have it display both in one cell depending on what is entered?

For example if I enter `$5` it would display `$5.00` and if I enter `5%` it would display `5 %`

If this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO if you wanted to do this with custom number formatting, all by itself.

This could be accomplished if you were OK with using VBA to set the custom number formatting at the time of value entry using the Worksheet_Change() event procedure.

Like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect([a1:a10], Target) Is Nothing Then
            Select Case True
                Case Left$(Target.NumberFormat, 1) = "$": Target.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
                Case Target.NumberFormat = "0%":          Target.NumberFormat = "0 %"
            End Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Note the `[a1:a10]` near the top of the procedure. This specifies the range on the sheet that will respond to this dynamic formatting. Edit that range to your liking.

Comment: I'm not familiar with VBA. Would there be a downside to doing this? Where would I enter this code?

Comment: The only downside is that users of that particular workbook would need to allow macros when the workbook is opened.

Comment: Here is where to place the VBA code. From the worksheet, press Alt-F11 on the keyboard. The VBEditor should open. On the project explorer on the left, double-click on the name of the sheet from the workbook where you want this behavior to occur. A large white window should appear to the right. Paste the code there. Save the file. That's it.